# Can I make Swiffy produce SVG markup instead of a canvas?

Tags: canvas, svg, google-swiffy

I use [Google Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) to export Flash files into formats that can be adapted by modern browsers. But recently Google updated its feature so that I can only export to `<canvas>` rather than getting raw SVG markup text code, which is what I've expected.

Is there any simple way to convert the  thing into SVG markup code?

Comment: If they have removed the SVG feature you are probably stuck with canvas or an older version of Swiffy. Content on canvas is bitmap/pixels and cannot be converted to SVG (in an easy way).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Thanks for pointing this out. But I found the generated content can be zoomed without any loss, it doesn't look like bitmap. It's really weird.

Comment: It's probably because the base data is stored as vector data and using canvas to simply rasterize it. You could probably use the base data (seem to be in JSON) to generate a SVG instead.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Thanks, so anyway it's impossible to get a SVG directly from the generated canvas, right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Canvas will only produce a simple bitmap.

Comment: @K3N I found your response here after posting this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516617/how-does-google-swiffy-maintain-vectors-in-canvas-tag.  Could you elaborate on how swiffy is doing this?  I can't find any other resources online that detail how to maintain vectors in canvas like swiffy does. Thanks.